# How to lookup in the same document under a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am having below document in MongoDB [UPDATE : Shortened the document]

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a8f"
      },
      "categories": [
        {
          "measureValues": [
            "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a95",
            "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a99"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "measures": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a93"
      },
      "name": {
        "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a92": {
          "nodeType": "nodeName",
          "value": "measure-1"
        }
      },
      "measureValues": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a95"
          },
          "measureValues": {
            "nodeName": {
              "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a94": {
                "nodeType": "nodeName",
                "value": "measureValue",
                "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
              }
            },
            "comment": {
              "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a97": {
                "nodeType": "comment",
                "value": "this is a comment",
                "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
              }
            }
          },
          "categoriesIds": [
            "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a91"
          ],
          "measureName": "measure-1"
        },
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a99"
          },
          "measureValues": {
            "nodeName": {
              "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a98": {
                "nodeType": "nodeName",
                "value": "measureValue",
                "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
              }
            },
            "date": {
              "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a9b": {
                "nodeType": "date",
                "value": "2023-02-02",
                "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
              }
            }
          },
          "categoriesIds": [
            "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a91"
          ],
          "measureName": "measure-1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.ProjectGroup"
}
```

I want to fetch the "measureValues" under "measures" where the id of the "measureValues" is matching with the id of the measureValues under categories. I want to include the measureValue object under categories instead of just the Ids.

How can I do that? I tried writing aggregate pipeline, but it failed.

My Output should look like below.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a8f"
      },
      "categories": [
        {
          "measureValues": [
            {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a95"
              },
              "measureValues": {
                "nodeName": {
                  "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a94": {
                    "nodeType": "nodeName",
                    "value": "measureValue",
                    "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
                  }
                },
                "comment": {
                  "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a97": {
                    "nodeType": "comment",
                    "value": "this is a comment",
                    "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
                  }
                }
              },
              "categoriesIds": [
                "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a91"
              ],
              "measureName": "measure-1"
            },
            {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a99"
              },
              "measureValues": {
                "nodeName": {
                  "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a98": {
                    "nodeType": "nodeName",
                    "value": "measureValue",
                    "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
                  }
                },
                "date": {
                  "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a9b": {
                    "nodeType": "date",
                    "value": "2023-02-02",
                    "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.DataObj"
                  }
                }
              },
              "categoriesIds": [
                "64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a91"
              ],
              "measureName": "measure-1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.myapp.cqrsdemo.model.ProjectGroup"
}
```

Comment: Would you show your desired output and your aggregation pipeline attempts?

Comment: Can you simplify the problem.  It seems you have posted a large example document, where many of the fields play no role in your problem.  These extra data points make it more difficult for someone to assist.  #help-me-help-you

Comment: @barrypicker - I have updated the shortened the input document. And also uploaded the desired output.

Comment: Still a rather big document. And what is the pipeline you tried? What do you mean by "it failed"?

Comment: Having dynamic key names (like `64cbeb62b669cd29a5719a9b`) is usually a poor design, it makes your life more difficult. And it looks like you mix `ObjectId` (`$oid`) with string values, which is also not very smart.

Comment: With the given data it would be simply `db.collection.aggregate([{ $project: { _class: 1, sections: { categories: { $first: "$measures.measureValues" } } } }])` But you lack some information: Which array can be empty? Are the array elements always unique? It is also not clear which elements are defined as array despite they have always only one element (and thus should be better **not** stored as an array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

1. Create a var `measureValuesArr` and store inside it a single flatten array of all `measureValues` under all `measures`
2. Since the `sections.categories.measureValues` is a double nested array (inside an array on arrays) use double `$map` to get into all instances of it.
3. Use `$arrayElemAt` with `$indexOfArray` to find the matching `measureValues` item inside `measureValuesArr`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      sections: {$let: {
          vars: {measureValuesArr: {$reduce: {
                input: "$measures",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.measureValues"]}
          }}},
          in: {$map: {
              input: "$sections",
              as: "s",
              in: {$mergeObjects: [
                  "$$s",
                  {categories: {$map: {
                        input: "$$s.categories",
                        as: "c",
                        in: {$mergeObjects: [
                            "$$c",
                            {measureValues: {$map: {
                                  input: "$$c.measureValues",
                                  as: "m",
                                  in: {$arrayElemAt: [
                                      "$$measureValuesArr",
                                      {$indexOfArray: [
                                          "$$measureValuesArr._id",
                                          {$toObjectId: "$$m"}
                                      ]}
                                  ]}
                            }}}
                        ]}
                  }}}
              ]}
          }}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3b5V0jAr1-8)

*This solution assumes that a matching object does exists somewhere under `measures` if there is an option that it does not exists, an handling of this case should be added to the query.